# White of an egg

Tags: solutions, colloids

What happens when you dissolve white of an egg in water?
Firstly, what's white of an egg? Is it the white part? Or implies whole of an egg? I couldn't relate much of it with colloids, either.

Answer (score 3):

The white clear liquid in the egg is nothing but albumin. It helps in supplying nutrition to the yolk and gives strength to the yolk during the formation of chicken. White part doesn't imply whole of an egg.
       The composition of that white liquid is 90% water and 10% protein. 
       If you dissolve it in water, then it is nothing but a colloidal solution. We can call it as emulsion as it is 'protein in water '.
    Hope helpful..

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was quite simple. I got one more question for you: what happens when you pass sulfur vapors through cold water.

Comment: @user208322 If you have a different question, please post it as a new question, not a comment.

Comment: The white of the egg, albumin, should be dissolved in cold water as in hot water it clogs.